# Missing fields in API response in Production

Tags: image, rest, mern, dev-to-production

I have a mern app that I am using to fetch packages from my backend.
It works in development but not in production when I host it on AWS EC2.

I figured out that the reason it's not working id because I am getting incomplete response back in production. How is it even possible? I am frustrated right now.

Attaching some images and console logs in development and production.
The field packageImages is missing in production response!

[image: Production API Response]

[image: Dev API response]

Because of this I am getting error about trying to read properties of undefined.
Please someone guide me with this.

Comment: Hard to tell anything about this without the code. Obviously the variable does not contain what you sent in the screenshots.

Comment: What code do you need to see? It is an axios get request to a route, ` const res = await axios.get('/api/packages', config);

                const data = await res.data;
                console.log(data);
                await setPackages(data);
                setIsLoading(false);
     `